# Replace specific exception as part of try/catch retry mechanism

Tags: c#

Looking for a most efficient way to replace some specific exception and to leave others exceptions treatment the same the same.

```
try
{
  // some business logic
}
catch(UniqueConstraintViolationException uex) when (!uex.IsFatal() && !ShouldRetry(descriptor, command, uex, ref retryResult))
{
 throw new ItemAlreadyExistsException("Item already exists", uex);
}
catch (Exception ex) when (!ex.IsFatal() && ShouldRetry(descriptor, command, ex, ref retryResult))
{                        
}
```

Comment: Just another catch block with the specific exception type. But we don't write not yet written and working code here, sorry.

Comment: This code is working, just wandered whether it's a best way to do it, since making check of ShouldRetry twice.

Comment: @Genady Here you should share working code. `//some business logic` can't be considered as real code. This kind of question is more suitable for StackOverflow IMO.

Comment: This kind of logic-heavy use is exactly why I dreaded the introduction of the `when` keyword. It's no longer clear whether a given exception is being handled or not.

Comment: Welcome to code review. While this may be working, the missing business logic and the missing code executing the try block makes the question off-topic for code review. There simply isn't enough code to provide a context for the usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the exception type inside the catch block in order to omit the `when` clause duplication:

```cs
try
{
    // some business logic
}
catch (Exception ex) 
    when (!ex.IsFatal() && ShouldRetry(descriptor, command, ex, ref retryResult))
{
    if(ex is UniqueConstraintViolationException)
        throw new ItemAlreadyExistsException("Item already exists", uex);
}
```

Comment: imho, much better. plus, I'd move `!ex.IsFatal() && ShouldRetry(descriptor, command, ex, ref retryResult)` into a new function that checks for `!ex.IsFatal()` before `ShouldRetry`, to make it shorter and more readable.

Comment: Thanks for checking, basically looking to throw `ItemAlreadyExistsException` instead of `UniqueConstraintViolationException` only after all retry attempt(=10) were finished, not for each retry.

Comment: @Genady Please bear in mind that in this case only the inner exception will contain the original stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

Currently thinking about a following solution:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex) when (!ex.IsFatal() && ShouldRetry(descriptor, command, ex, ref retryResult))
{
}
catch (UniqueConstraintViolationException uex)
{
    throw new ItemAlreadyExistsException("Item already exists", uex);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was referring to in my comment. I didn't complain about _not working_ code, but _**not yet written**_, Also you're presenting us a hypothetical stub code, and not your real code, which usually is a requirement for review here. Please check in the [help] how to ask a good question at CR.

Comment: Of cause this code is working and fully covered by tests, my question whether it's a most efficient way from c# point of view.